# Unexpected rename/deleted message while git merge

Tags: java, git

I have two branches, Hotfix and R1. We made some changes in Hotfix and now we have to merge both the branches. I checked out both branches on my local and executed following command.

```
git merge --no-commit Hotfix R1
```

My expectation was R1 branch will merge into Hotfix branch.Git will display the conflicts and I'll fix those conflicts. Instead I got following message in place of all the conflicts.

```
CONFLICT (rename/delete): path/to/some/file/FileName.java deleted in HEAD and renamed in R1. Version R1 of path/to/some/file/FileName.java
```

For some files I might expect that somebody deleted or renamed the file. But this message is coming for 300 files. And both the branches are not so far. So I think I am interpreting wrong meaning of the message. Can someone please explain me that what does this message really mean?

Comment: Are you using Windows? There git has problems when file names are rewritten with e.g. capital letters, like "testfile" becomes "TestFile". Then deletes could be recognized and renames dependent on which computer you are.

Comment: Yes I am on windows. But filenames at both places are identical. There is no difference of capital letters anywhere.